# Most efficient way to have 1 template for parent, 1 template for child categories?

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy

This is the setup I want:

For category-15.php:

```
 Child Category A (list of all posts inside)
     Post A from Child Category A
     Post B from Child Category A
     Post C from Child Category A
 Child Category B (list of all posts inside)
     Post A from Child Category B
     Post B from Child Category B
```

And for ALL child categories under category-15, I want them to display:

```
Child Category Title (paginated with 2 posts each)
     Post A
     Post B
```

As I understand, WordPress does not have something like:

category-15.php (for parent)

category-15-child.php (for children)

Right now, I have a query in my category-15 that checks if the category has children (if yes, display the code for the parent; if no, display code for children).

Is there a cleaner and faster way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you've done it. It's a great solution to your problem.

Comment: @deflime Just worried because I've got maybe 3-4 queries inside and wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: I don't think there's any way around that if you want native pagination.

Comment: @Anon you can have 100 queries more, as long as they are time efficient. You'll need to look at how much longer does it take to run these extra queries. How time efficient are your queries. If the impact is absolute minimal, why worry about that. On the other hand, look for an alternative if these queries have a big negative impact on time.

Comment: @deflime I'm actually having issues paginating the child categories, ha!

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thank you! I'm not that experienced with ensuring efficiency in WP queries so I had no idea if I was toeing the line in terms of speed. Nothing noticeably negative so I think I'm on the safe side for now.

Comment: @Anon Download and install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). This will print all queries and how efficient are they, so you will be able to see how fast a query is executed. This will also tell you immediately if a query is taking to much time. Just don't use it on a production site

Comment: I don't know if this will help you out at all but this is how I declare pagination in `WP_Query`: `'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

Comment: Thank you @PieterGoosen. That looks bloody useful. Any reason why it would be bad to test it on production? Its results seem to be admin-only in any case.

Comment: @deflime You're welcome to check the other unanswered question I have posted (which has your method), though I'm not rushing to solve that one anymore :) Thank you!

Comment: This plugin is for development purposes only, and really has no other use than that. You really don't want to run this unnecessary

Comment: @PieterGoosen Noted, thanks! Also, yipes. I ran it on the page and it's freaking out with my queries for attachments. Looks like I have to look through things :( Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck. Glad I could be of some assistance